# Disappearing questions

Tags: support, questions

Over the last few months I have noticed that the counter of the number of questions I asked went from 125 to 122. Any idea why? Are questions being purged?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do (did) you have any closed questions with 0 or negative score and no answers? There is an automatic cleanup of such questions.

There's also the "[roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year?lq=1)" which deletes low-scoring, unanswered, low view questions after a year.

Also, if you have anything migrated to another site, the "stub" would be eventually deleted on the original site.

Comment: I don't think so. Is there anyway I can check? I don't see anything in "deleted recent questions" (except 2 questions I deleted myself).

Comment: I Moderator might be able to tell you. (I was just about to suggest you ensure that the "recently deleted posts" checkbox was checked.)

Comment: I wasn't aware of this Roomba. I am really disgusted: I'm going to lose many of my questions. Stack Exchange has totally no respect for user content.

Comment: I started using webapps around 1.2 year ago so roomba is indeed most likely the cause. Questions that are 365 days old + no upvote + less than 365*1.5 = 547 views is quite common. E.g. [this question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/58004/18147) should be deleted in 2 days if nobody upvote it or leave a comment... I am still interested in the answer!

Comment: So I counted. This March,  around 10 questions of mine will be deleted by Roomba: 2 have already been deleted, 1 has just been saved by AI E, and the others are waiting for silent deletion: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/58876/18147 ; http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/58854/18147 ; http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/58765/18147 ; http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/58427/18147 ; http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/58423/18147 ; http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/58315/18147.

Comment: Feature request on meta: [Notify the OP when a question is about to be removed by Roomba](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250816/178179)